# Neo4J User Defined Functions - How to deploy new functions?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm learning Cypher since yesterday and I read about the user defined functions. 
There's many material on how to use the functions, but not many on how to deploy new ones.

I would like to try out but I'm having a hard time on finding a step-by-step tutorial on how to deploy new functions to my desktop app.

The ones I have found bypass some concepts as they were too obvious. And maybe they are for someone coming from a Java background or whatever the background is you're supposed to have when using Neo4J.  ...But I come from a Javascript background. I'm used to npm, never heard of maven (just an example).

It would be nice you someone could help with a detailed step-by-step tutorial on how to write and deploy a new user defined function in Neo4J.

Answer (score 3):

For helping a bit.

User defined functions are only writables in Java code for now. They're server extensions. You write the code with a Java editor (outside Neo4j) and publish it under a Java Archive (a file with extension *.jar*) into the */plugins* directory of your Neo4j installation (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/cypher-functions/).

Many useful procedures already exist with APOC extension ([https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/cypher-functions/)) depending of your Neo4j server  version.

Try them first bfeore developping yours, especially if you're starting with CYPHER. Some of them should solve your usuals demands.

All of extensions are taking effect after a restart of Neo4j.

Note : Maven is a dependency manager for Java.